# General definition of conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a problem with understanding the general definition of conditional expectation with respect to some sigma algebra. The definition says that for any $A \in \mathcal F$ we have
$\int_A Xd\mathbb P = \int_A \mathbb E(X|\mathcal F) d\mathbb P $, that is $X = \mathbb E(X|\mathcal F) $ a.s.

Now let's say $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are random variables for $i = 1,...,n$ and I want to calculate $\mathbb E(X_1 + ... + X_k | Y_1,...,Y_k)$. Is it always OK to write that the expectation equals $X_1 + ... + X_k$? It's just using the definition, right? I don't quite get the concept, it's beyond my cognitive abilities. Thanks in advance for clearing my doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, without any additional assumption all you can write is $$\mathbb E(X_1 + ... + X_k | Y_1,...,Y_k) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E(X_i| Y_1,...,Y_k)$$

Now, if each $X_i$ is measurable with respect to the sigma-algebra generated by $Y_1,\ldots, Y_k$, then $E(X_i| Y_1,...,Y_k) = X_i$ and you  get indeed $$\mathbb E(X_1 + ... + X_k | Y_1,...,Y_k) = X_1 + ... + X_k$$

Comment: I get it, $X_i$ must be $\sigma(Y_1,...,Y_k)$ - measurable and then we can apply the definition of conditional expectation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The definition says that if $Z=\mathsf{E}[X\mid\mathcal{F}]$ a.s., then  $\mathsf{E}[X1_A]=\mathsf{E}[Z1_A]$ for all $A\in \mathcal{F}$. This does not imply that $X=Z$ a.s. Consider a simple case when $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(B)=\{\emptyset,B,B^c,\Omega\}$ for some measurable set $B$. Then the conditional expectation of $X$ given $\mathcal{F}$ is the "average" of $X$ on $B$($B^c$) when $\omega\in B$ ($B^c$).